# angular material validate form by external event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a multi-part form, and I was hoping to have an external next/prev navigation for it. However, I need to be able to validate each part of the form when I navigate to next.

I have the following sample form definition:

```
<form layout="column" name="nProfileForm1">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>City</label>
        <input ng-model="profile.city" required="" name="nCity">
        <div ng-messages="nProfileForm1.nCity.$error"  ng-if="nProfileForm1.nCity.$touched&&!nProfileForm1.nCity.$valid">
            <div ng-message="required">City is required.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

If the field is interacted with,then validation is working find and error text is correctly shown. However, I cant figure out a way to trigger the validation of all the form fields if external event takes place. It seems somewhat wrong to add own submit button to every form part. What I am looking for is something similar to what schema-form does:

```
$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate')
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Essentially, int he following example I want the field to light up with red once I press next:
http://codepen.io/Vladimir_M/pen/OWEjOd

UPDATE: updated codePen to include one solution that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I've found one way to achieve the effect I was after with minimal code. Getting the form's scope and setting the form's $submitted property to true does the trick. It evaluates the entire form.

```
 $scope.doSubmit = function(){
    var formScope = angular.element(nProfileForm1).scope();
    formScope.nProfileForm1.$submitted = true;
  }
```

Feel free to suggest better ways.